# Wordpress url rewrite issue for wordpress rest api url

Tags: url-rewriting

I have an issue of url rewrite. A page created from wp-admin in which the title suppose profile and a custom template are assigned to the profile page. I used a custom permalink structure(/%postname%) for the site.

/institution/?institutionname=Commonwealth-College-Inc.
needed
/institution/Commonwealth-College-Inc.

/institution/Commonwealth-College-Inc.